# Deleting the first item of every element in a string in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python. This list has sublist in it. 
for example:

```
 [['85.', 'Document', 'will', 'discuss', 'allegations,', 'or', 'measures', 'being', 'taken', 'against,', 'corrupt', 'public', 'officials', 'of', 'any', 'governmental', 'jurisdiction', 'worldwide.'], ['56.', 'Document', 'will', 'include', 'a', 'prediction', 'about', 'the', 'prime', 'lending', 'rate,', 'or', 'will', 'report', 'an', 'actual', 'prime', 'rate', 'move.'], and so on]
```

when i print mylist[0], i get the following:

```
['85.', 'Document', 'will', 'discuss', 'allegations,', 'or', 'measures', 'being', 'taken', 'against,', 'corrupt', 'public', 'officials', 'of', 'any', 'governmental', 'jurisdiction', 'worldwide.']
```

when i print mylist[0][0] i get `85.`

I am new to python and i dont understand how to access these values(85, 56, and so on) inside a for loop, so that i can delete all the numbers. i.e 85, 56, and so on.

1. Also I have a similar list `[[1, 23], [2, 34], [3, 45], [1, 45], [2, 44]]`
   and i want to add all the second elements where the 1st element is the same. i.e i want to add 23 + 45 (because both have 1 as their 1st element). I understand i need a for loop, but i am new to python, and i am not able to understand the loops.

Comment: Before you ask really basic questions on SO, read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html). It covers everything you just mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the first elements:

```
zip(*your_list)[0]
```

`zip(*some_iterable)` does some kind of matrix inversion - you should play a bit with it to get an idea.

To remove all the first values from a set of iterables you may choose a few ways.  E.g.:

```
[item[1:] for item in your_list]  # probably the best
zip(*zip(*your_list)[1:])  # tricky and probably slow one
```

To sum your values you'd need a dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = [[1, 23], [2, 34], [3, 45], [1, 45], [2, 44]]
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for item in l:
    d[item[0]] += item[1]

>>> d.items()
[(1, 68), (2, 78), (3, 45)]
```

We use `defaultdict` here to be able to perform this `d[item[0]] += item[1]` assigment.  With simple `dict` we'd get a `KeyError`, since our `d` is empty.  But `defaultdict` in this case just returns default value - `int()`, which is `0`.

Comment: printing zip(*mylist)[0] gives me all the numbers. [85., 56. and so on] how do i display my new zipped list without numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, python treats each part of mylist[0][0] as 2 separate commands.
The first call: `mylist[0]` returns

```
    ['85.', 'Document', 'will', 'discuss', 'allegations,', 'or', 'measures', 'being', 'taken', 'against,', 'corrupt', 'public', 'officials', 'of', 'any', 'governmental', 'jurisdiction', 'worldwide.']
```

which is the first item in your original list. The second part gets the `<first call>[0]` or the 0th element of  THAT list. It should return `85`.

In order to access the first element of the next list, you would use `mylist[1][0]` (get the 2nd element, return the 1st element from that list...

To obtain a list of *all* the first elements in the list, use a list comprehension:

```
    first_items = [item[0] for item in mylist]
    print(first_items)
    ...
    [85, 56,... and so on]
```

To 'delete' all the first elements of list, you would do something called slicing. You can create a new list using *only* the second element (and so on) of each list:

```
    new_list = [item[1:] for item in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem:

```
first_values = [int(sublist[0]) for sublist in data]
```

For your second problem:

```
x = [[1, 23], [2, 34], [3, 45], [1, 45], [2, 44]]

dicto = {}

for sublist in x:
    try:
        dicto[sublist[0]] = dicto[sublist[0]] + sublist[1]
    except KeyError:
        dicto[sublist[0]] = sublist[1]
```